# Upload file to AWS S3 using php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to create a php script which will be able to upload a text file to my ASW S3 bucket.

I have tried the method which is there on AWS site but sadly that ain't proper, I mean it's not end to end.

I have installed the AWS PHP SDK on my instance.

Then I did what's written in the sample code i.e.

```
<?php
    use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$bucket = 'cst';
$keyname = 'sampleUpload';
// $filepath should be absolute path to a file on disk                      
$filepath = '/var/www/html/po/si/mag/sahara.txt';

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory();

// Upload a file.
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'       => $bucket,
    'Key'          => $keyname,
    'SourceFile'   => $filepath,
    'ContentType'  => 'text/plain',
    'ACL'          => 'public-read',
    'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
    'Metadata'     => array(    
        'param1' => 'value 1',
        'param2' => 'value 2'
    )
));

echo $result['ObjectURL'];

?>
```

Obviously, I haven't added the aws key nor the aws secret key so it won't work. But then nothing is specified in the tutorial either. So am kinda lost.

Secondly, I tried using this [code](https://gist.github.com/anubhaw2091/cc04fc9a60979123c0abb4e05f192d2e) :

It's also not working.

Thirdly, I tried this [article](https://www.sanwebe.com/2015/09/direct-upload-to-amazon-aws-s3-using-php-html).

It's working when am using it with html but I am not really able to create a php only script where I can just specify the file location, and the file get's uploaded to the server.

Any help is highly appreciated. I searched a lot, but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: "_It's working when am using it with html but I am not really able to create a php only script where I can just specify the file location, and the file get's uploaded to the server."_ I'm confused - what exactly do you need help with here?  Does the code in the question work as expected?

Comment: No, the last link works as the title says i.e Direct Upload to Amazon AWS S3 Using PHP & HTML. I want to upload it only through php. I intent to make a POST request to php file with the location and the file should be uploaded to the s3.

Comment: So have you made an HTML form with a file upload input?

Comment: Yes. @EatPeanutButter

Comment: Again I ask, what do you need help with on this?  You say you want to upload a file via a post request....  Do you need help posting the file? Uploading the file? Accessing the $_FILES superglobal? Retrieving a file from your S3 instance? Help me out here

Comment: I want to make a php script without html part in it. And, I want help regarding uploading a file to s3 bucket. Like if I call a link e.g www.example.com/upload and pass the location of the file via post req i.e $filepath=whateverIpass and the file should be uploaded to s3 bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a guess, but did you add your credentials inside your HTML code using hidden inputs? Cause I just had a very quick look at this page: https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434/ and it seems like you can set your credentials using HTML. And my guess is the class will automatically take care of that.

If my guess is right, you do need to add the credentials to your instance:

```
// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory();
```

like

```
// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
  'version' => 'latest',
  'region'  => 'us-west-2', //add correct region
  'credentials' => array(
    'key' => <YOUR_AWS_KEY>,
    'secret'  => <YOUR_AWS_SECRET>
  )
));
```

It probably depends on the version of the sdk you're using, whether you need above mentioned code or this one (notice the missing credentials array):

```
// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
  'version' => 'latest',
  'region'  => 'us-west-2', //add correct region
  'key' => <YOUR_AWS_KEY>,
  'secret'  => <YOUR_AWS_SECRET>
));
```

EDIT:
Just to show what exactly worked in my case, this is my complete code. The path I executed:
http://myurl.com/index.php?path=./test.txt

code:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$bucket = 'sdl-images';
$keyname = '*** Your Object Key ***';
// $filepath should be absolute path to a file on disk                      
$filepath = $_GET['path'];

// Instantiate the client.
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
  'version' => 'latest',
  'region'  => <YOUR_REGION E.G. eu-west-1>,
  'credentials' => array(
    'key' => <YOUR_AWS_KEY>,
    'secret'  => <YOUR_AWS_SECRET>
  )
));

// Upload a file.
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'       => $bucket,
    'Key'          => $keyname,
    'SourceFile'   => $filepath,
    'ContentType'  => 'text/plain',
    'ACL'          => 'public-read',
    'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'
));

echo $result['ObjectURL'];
```

Comment: I am able to upload the file through browser but I want to upload it directly through the php script. i.e call a link and pass the location of the file as a parameter and the file should be uploaded to it. Imagine clicking a button on android phone and the file get'ss uploaded to the bucket,

Comment: Well that should not be a big problem? You just need to make sure the namespace is loaded correctly, in my case I've added `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` at the top of my file and just called the file directly. You could add a parameter `http://url.nl/?uploadfile=/test.txt` and add that parameter (`$_GET['uploadfile']`) to your filepath...?

Comment: Check out my edited answer, I posted my complete code as example

Comment: Thanks. I think I was looking for this approach exactly but am getting *The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.* error always. I am sure that the keys are right !! Any idea?

Comment: You did not accidentally switched the key with the secret? And made sure region and bucket values are correct? You wrote it worked fine with the HTML part, so I guess AWS is configured correctly. So in that case I have no other clue either.